# Regex replace text between two characters, first occurrence

Tags: regex, sed

I need to remove all the text between the charcters: `{` and `}` in a phrase like:

```
the car {is} black {and} big
```

I run the Linux command:

```
sed -i 's/{.*}//g' myfile.txt
```

But the result is: `the car big` instead of what I wanted: `the car black big`. The regex found the biggest enclosing curly brackets and removed the text between the, but I wanted to treat every closure singularly.
Is there a regex expression that can do the job?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This line should help:

```
sed 's/{[^}]*}//g'
```

The regex `.*` does greedy match, it will match the first `{` till the last `}` in your input.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching, thanks